# Display text on rect using D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am developing Normalized stacked bar chart using d3.js,and trying to append a text on rect.It is getting appended when i inspect in browser.But it is not visible.I want something like this,[image]

Here is my code,

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .11);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#404041", "#00adef", "#bbbdc0", "#d1d2d4", "#d3d3d3"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format("10"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 20)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("Nstackedbardata.json", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) {return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.ages.forEach(function(d) { d.y0 /= y0; d.y1 /= y0; });
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.ages[0].y1 - a.ages[0].y1; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .style("fill", "#bbbdc0")
      .append("text")
      .attr("class","barChartAxisValue");
    var insertLinebreaks = function (d) {
        var el = d3.select(this);
        var words = d.split(' ');
        el.text('');

        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(words[i]);
            if (i > 0)
                tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '12');
        }
    };
    svg.selectAll('g.x.axis g text').each(insertLinebreaks);
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .style("fill", "#bbbdc0")
      .append("text")
      .attr("class","barChartAxisValue")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("x",-70)
      .attr("y", -15)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Percentage");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",0)"; });


  var sandeep= state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name);})
      .append("text")
      .attr("fill","#fff")
       .style("stroke-width", 1)
      .style({"font-size":"18px","z-index":"999999999"})
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return ((d.y1-d.y0)*100).toFixed(0);});


});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot append `text` elements to `rect` elements.

Instead, you should keep them as separate children of the parent `g`:

```
  var sandeep= state.selectAll(".data")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
      .enter();

   sandeep.append("rect")
      .classed('data', true)
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name);});

   sandeep
      .append("text")
      .classed('data', true)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return (y(d.y1) + y(d.y0)) / 2; }) // Center text
      .attr("fill","#fff")
      .style("stroke-width", 1)
      .style({"font-size":"18px","z-index":"999999999"})
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return ((d.y1-d.y0)*100).toFixed(0);});
```

Comment: I am facing same issue https://plnkr.co/edit/cVITU9y19MoEfrIMsVYf?p=preview . Tried your solution its not working. Any idea where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to ShaMoh's question on the accepted answer. I would have put this in a comment under his comment but im not allowed to yet.

I know that this is hella old and ShaMoh is probably dead by now, or has solved his issue, but for anybody who finds this and is wondering what is wrong with his plnkr code:

He defines "bar" as a rect element appended to "serie", one for each d in data in this code:

```
var bar = serie.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) {
                return d;
            })
            .enter().append("rect")
```

Then, later he appends his "text" to "bar" (which is a 'rect' element):

```
 bar.append("text")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x(d[1]);
            })
            .attr("dy", "1.35em")
            .text(function (d) { return d; });
```

So he ends up with a 'g' grouping element classed as "serie", with a 'rect' element for each d in .data, and a 'text' element appended to each 'rect':

[image: html Layout]

What he needs to do is append his 'text' element to his 'g' grouping element, which he calls "serie". That way his 'g' holds the 'rect's appended to it, onefor each slice of the bar, plus the 'text' elements appened. Instead of being appended to the 'rect', and not displayed, the text is appended to the same 'g' as the 'rect':

```
 <g class="serie">
     <rect></rect>
     <rect></rect>
     <text></text>
    </g>
```